# Aggregate data from msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory

Tags: sql-server, sql-agent

each time i run agent job it puts some data to the log. I can access those data via T-SQL like this: `SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory WHERE step_id = 0`. It will show me summary information about job.

Problem is that if there was a step with failed but "on failure action" was "go to next step" `run_status` will show success.

I've try to aggregate data from `step_id <> 0` but i don't know how to distinguish each run of a job.

Can You help me with that problem? Best result would be additional column with distinct list of statuses that appeared in a job showed by first query.

What i want to achieve is a daily raport of a jobs that ran (some of them multiple time during the day) last day.

Answer (score 0):

Try joining your query to:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[sysjobsteps]
```

This includes the field last_run_outcome.

MSDN link of complete table:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187387.aspx

Comment: it's great for last run, but what with a previous runs?

Comment: I think job history is always an issue with the SQL agent, unless using third party tools that give point in time information. 

Are you aware that all job history is purged in the agent settings? If you right click the agent and go to properties. Then history. By default only 1000 rows of data are available in MSDB.

Previously I've done things to move all agent job data into my own DBA style reporting database. Or add a step to each job that trasnfers all outcome data from its last run to a table that doesn't get emptied.